# Datatable select everything everything below

Tags: c#, select, datatable

I have some pseudo code here and would like some help on the syntax.

The datatable looks something like this:

```
id      OrderID          Date           is_live
--      -------          ----           -------
1       abc              08/9/13        No
2       abc              12/9/13        No
3       bcd              13/9/13        Yes
4       abc              14/9/13        No
5       bcd              14/9/13        Yes

DataTable table = [function that populates table]
for each DataRow row in table


    if there are rows below selected row with same OrderID AND is_live = No
        "there are records below"

    else 
        "no records below"
```

Basically for each row, it would compare it with all the rows below it. If there is another OrderID that matches AND the is_live = "No" then it will 'do some stuff'

Comment: Assuming that the Date is always ordered from the earliest to latest

Comment: I din get your question first of all..Can you elaborate it..

Comment: I am a bit stuck on the row count function to get to to return all the records below selected row IF there are any rows below. I will elaborate in the question

Comment: What means _below_ in this context? Do you want _there are records below_ for every row that has another row with the same `OrderId` and `is_live ='No'`? So if row 1 and row 2 meet this condition should both rows output it or just the first? What means first, ordered by the index of the `DataRow` in the table or by the `Date`/`DateTime` in that column? By the way, what type do these columns have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Select Method of the DataTable, which will return an Array of DataRows, then all you need to do is use the Count/Length of the Array.

```
dataTable.Select("Date < #"+row.Date.ToString("d")+"# AND is_live = 'No' AND OrderID ='"+row.OrderID+"'")
```

As long as the columns in the dataTable match the Table presented.

Comment: would not consider further rows of same date though. Not sure if this is a requirement.

Comment: I was thinking about using something similar but was stuck on the syntax to do so.

the date is there so when the data table is populated (by sql) it would sort and force it to show the earliest date first

Comment: I don't quite understand the ("d") part of the code. could you please explain?

Comment: the .ToString("d") will format the date to a shortened date i.e. dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: I just managed to implement the solution but this only shows me a total of records found with the matching fields. Is there a way to show everything below the current record? eg when I am on the 2nd loop, the count should only return me 1 as there is 1 other record below the current one that matches the field